# how to run scrapy from python script

Tags: python, scrapy

my file list:

```
.
|-- lf
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- items.py
|   |-- items.pyc
|   |-- pipelines.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   `-- spiders
|       |-- bbc.py
|       |-- bbc.pyc
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- __init__.pyc
|       |-- lwifi.py
|       `-- lwifi.pyc
|-- scrapy.cfg
`-- script.py
```

items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class LfItem(Item):
    topic = Field();
```

script.py:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from lf.spiders.lwifi import LwifiSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

spider = LwifiSpider(domain='Lifehacker.co.in')
settings = get_project_settings()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
crawler.start()
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

lwifi.py:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
class LwifiSpider(Spider):
    name = "lwifi"  
    def __init__(self, **kw):
       super(LwifiSpider, self).__init__(**kw)
       url = kw.get('url') or kw.get('domain') or 'lifehacker.co.in/others/Dont-Use-      Personal-Information-in-Your-Wi-Fi-Network-Name/articleshow/45407704.cms'
       if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
           url = 'http://%s/' % url
       self.url = url
       self.allowed_domains = ["lifehacker.co.in/others/Dont-Use-Personal-Information-in-Your-Wi-Fi-Network-Name/articleshow/45407704.cms"]

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.url, callback=self.parse)]

    def parse(self, response):
        topic = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract();
        print topic
```

i am new to python and scrapy. As a start i wrote a simple scrapy spider to run from python script (not using scrapinghub). My aim is to scrap the h1 from the page http://lifehacker.co.in/others/Dont-Use-Personal-Information-in-Your-Wi-Fi-Network-Name/articleshow/45407704.cms .The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from lf.spiders.lwifi import LwifiSpider
  File "/home/ajay/pythonpr/error/lf/lf/spiders/lwifi.py", line 7, in <module>
    class LwifiSpider(Spider):
  File "/home/ajay/pythonpr/error/lf/lf/spiders/lwifi.py", line 11, in LwifiSpider
    url = kw.get('url') or kw.get('domain') or 'lifehacker.co.in/others/Dont-Use-Personal-   Information-in-Your-Wi-Fi-Network-Name/articleshow/45407704.cms'
NameError: name 'kw' is not defined
```

please help.

Comment: What kind of errors do you observe?

Comment: @amg. Please edit your question and add the **whole traceback**.

Comment: @amg. That's not the whole traceback. Run the script in a console, and copy everything that python prints when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the traceback, you will see that the error occurs in the *body* of the `LwifiSpider` class:

```
    File "/home/.../lwifi.py", line 11, in LwifiSpider
```

If the error occurred in the `__init__` of that class you'd see a line like this instead:

```
    File "/home/.../lwifi.py", line 11, in __init__
```

So it would appear that there is some kind of indentation error that is causing the problematic line to be *outside* of the `__init__` method, where the `kw` argument cannot be seen.

Try re-indenting the whole of the `__init__` function, and make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces anywhere (any decent text editor should allow you to make all the whitespace visible).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps on [how to run Python/Ajax crawls](https://www.promptcloud.com/how-to-run-ajax-web-crawls/). [How to set interactive crawls using AJax](https://www.promptcloud.com/data-hub-blog/web-scraping-interactive-ajax-crawls/)